# Многоуровневое меню на сайте

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, в общих чертах, как делается вот такое вертикальное многоуровневое меню?

В каком направлении здесь нужно двигаться при верстке и какие плагины использовать?

Там нужно, чтобы по клику на крестик возле подпункта, внизу открывались еще дополнительные подпункты. Спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сделать первую часть этого меню можно обойтись обыкновенным `:hover`. Вторую часть нужно реализовать с помощью `Javascript`. Никаких плагинов для этого не надо. Пара строк кода. Но перед этим, конечно же, нужно все сверстать

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/237689)

Comment: @Sublihim какой вопрос, такой ответ. Ответьте лучше, кто ж запрещает

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день! http://joxi.ru/823oQQBf6dE9J2
Меню (1) появляется при ховере на основное меню, в пункт из (2) вкладываешь новый список (3) который позиционируешь либо относительно его родителя, те li (2) либо всего списка (1) и показываешь его при ховер на пункт меню (2). Все можно сделать без js, только на css

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать с адаптивной версткой, можно использовать Bootstrap 4.
Но в обычном Bootstrap 4 такого нету, но такое есть у умельцев создавать "аддоны" для bootstrap 4.

**Bootstrap 4 Responsive Navbar with Multi level Dropdowns:**
https://github.com/bootstrapthemesco/bootstrap-4-multi-dropdown-navbar

Comment: Я этот проект без Bootstrap делаю, нужно будет как-то без него обойтись...